# Angular Error: "mat-form-field' is not a known element"

Tags: angular, angular-material, stackblitz

Im using stackblitz code editor and im trying to implement calendar in my app using angular materials but got this error.

[image]

here's the link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2ucboy?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hello, i cant see any problem of importing MatModules. But i see that you bootstrap in main just Datepicker component. Try to bootsrap as default appComponent.

Comment: Hi there, please consider providing your code inline as links may go down or be inaccessible at any point.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, you are bootstrapping your app in `main.ts`? That's why your actual `app.module.ts` file is redundant. You need to import the relevant modules into your `main.ts` file, as that is where your `AppModule` is declared.

See [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rxcbho?file=src/main.ts) working demo.

Comment: its woring fine in angular example https://stackblitz.com/angular/anmqddxqxmy?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: your example has been bootstrapped in `main.ts` for other reasons, there's no need for you to do this. If you do, then you'll need to import the relevant modules in `main.ts`.